# MYSQL Query Problem: Select all threads, order by amount of no's who correspond to the thread

Tags: mysql, select

My title probably is a bit confusing, so here is my problem.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `b_posts` (
  `thread` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `no` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `gone` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`no`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `comment` (`comment`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I now need a query which selects ALL threads which are not gone (means gone is 0, if done is 1 this would mean the thread has been deleted). The order of which the threads are selected should be by the amount of no's who have the same thread like the original.

Further explanation:

```
thread | no | comment | gone
100 | 100 | hello there, this is the thread! | 0
100 | 102 | this is a reply in the thread 100 | 0
100 | 103 | another reply in the same thread | 0
104 | 104 | this is a different thread | 0
104 | 105 | a reply to the different thread | 0
```

I now want to get the following data in the following order with my query:

```
thread | no | comment | gone
100 | 100 | hello there, this is the thread! | 0
104 | 104 | this is a different thread | 0
```

(Thread starter is defined when thread == no)

Answer (score 0):

Since your qualifier of "thread = no" and "gone = 0", I saw no point in including them in the result columns... however, I did include the sub-count of total entries per thread

```
select b.thread,
       b.comment,
       postCounts.TotalEntries
   from
      b_posts b
         join ( select b2.thread, count(*) as TotalEntries 
                    from b_posts b2
                    group by b2.thread ) postCounts
            on b.thread = postcounts.thread
   where
          b.thread = b.no
      and b.gone = 0
   order by
      postCounts.TotalEntries DESC
```